# Branch prediction strategy of the 8086 microprocessor

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, x86-16

Does the 8086 microprocessor follow any branch prediction strategy? If yes then what is it? I googled a lot but did not find an answer to my question.

Comment: Quick Googling shows that it always fetched the next sequential instruction. http://www.cosc.brocku.ca/~bockusd/3p92/Local_Pages/8086_achitecture.htm

Answer (score 1):

No, the original 8086 CPU doesn't use branch prediction. Taken branches always cost 16 cycles, while not taken branches always cost 4 cycles.